# Custom status with guild number

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have another discord.js query which involves **custom statuses**. I want my bot's custom status to be "Being Used In # Guilds/Servers" where # is the number of guilds the bot will be in.

Note that by "custom status" I don't mean a Playing status:

[image: Playing Status]

I mean a custom status (without "Playing"):

[image: Custom Status]

(Yes, that is OG Clyde, because I had my account since the Christmas Vacation 2020.)

So some answers say that Discord.js V12 only has Playing Statuses, not Custom Statuses. Now I had a conversation with @jabaa (in the comments) which said that I should share my *own* research and code, or else people will downvote. But I cannot share, because I don't know which code to use. I know one to display memberCount in the status, but not guild numbers.

Comment: Please read the [tour] _"Don't ask about...

    Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)"_

Comment: @jabaa I cannot find an answer to this question.

Comment: You wanted to know why people downvoted your question. I gave you one possible reason. Posting questions without showing any code, approaches or research effort is usually a quick way to multiple downvotes.

Comment: @jabaa Which post is it? (And yes, I didn't notice the downvotes).

Comment: What do you mean with _"Which post is it"_?

Comment: @jabaa I mean, which post is the post saying "why people should not upvote bad questions".

Comment: Your comment _"I just got 10 reputation points!"_ shows that you didn't understand why your question was downvoted.

Comment: @jabaa I knew why (I discussed it in my edit), but [@MrMythical](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15781079/mrmythical) already found the answer. i hence accepted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I am using this in my bot too: here is the code

```js
//...
client.on('ready', () => {
//...
client.user.setActivity('othertext' + client.guilds.cache.size, {type : 'PLAYING'})
}

client.on('guildCreate', guild => {
//same code as 'ready'
})

client.on('guildDelete', guild => {
//also the same code as 'ready'
})
```

Now this was from my *human* memory but this is a start, just modify it with any errors you may have, hopefully there are none.
**NOTE:** If you are just putting the number of guilds, for some reason, make sure the add the '' after the client.guilds.cache.size, otherwise you will get an error saying it got a number but expected string

Comment: And of course, as you may have seen already, you cannot set it as a custom status, only Playing, Watching, etc.

Answer (score 0):

DJS does not currently have support for Custom Statuses the same way users do, so this is not possible at this time.

Comment: But playing statuses it has.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ActivityType),

> Bots cannot set a CUSTOM_STATUS, it is only for custom statuses
> received from users

`ClientUser.setStatus()` takes a `PresenceData` type as an argument, which in turn has an object `activity` and its property `type` that can be either `PLAYING, STREAMING, LISTENING, WATCHING` or `COMPETING`

Comment: Wait, `COMPETING`?

Comment: In the list on the discordjs website, `CUSTOM_STATUS` is listed. Why?

Comment: Yes, and the status would be `Competing in {name}` as stated [here](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#activity-object-activity-types). CUSTOM_STATUS is listed because it can be **retrieved** from users but not set.